# fetching & processing a json response from a return statement

Tags: python, flask, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

im only starting to learn programming (and python, flask) and I have a situation that I can't resolve on my own (or use of google).

i'm trying to access my youtube channel data via youtube data v3 and am using official google libraries for oauth, and data retrieval.

the code below is what i am using. the return of the method is working well, however it is only rendering the json response in my browser and i can't 'catch' it and process it.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
  if 'credentials' not in flask.session:
    return flask.redirect('authorize')

  credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
      **flask.session['credentials'])

  client = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
      API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)

  return channels_list_by_username(client,
    part='snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
    forUsername='username')
```

I was thinking of putting the call in a new variable, json.dump()-ing the response and accessing it like so, but it just doesn't work.

any help with this is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by catching it and processing it? What do you mean by "putting the call in a new variable ... but it doesn't work" ?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like you've got the right idea there, but *that's* what you need to show us, and describe what exactly "it just doesn't work" means.

Comment: @DanielleM. - bare with me on my terminology. the return statement (return channels_list_by_username) renders the entire json response in my browser. by 'catching and processing it' i mean to somehow put that json response in an object / variable that I can manipulate from code with the intent of filtering certain information from the response and using it elsewhere. hope this clarifies

Comment: @drissLikeThis The sentence after the block of code indicates that you have already solved this particular problem. If your solution didn't work, *that's* what you should be asking about.

Comment: @glibdud - you're right.so when I try to do the following 'result = channels_list_by_username' and then 'data = json.dumps(result)' i get: 'TypeError: <Response 1731 bytes [200 OK]> is not JSON serializable' . i think this has to do with parsing the response in a dict and then accessing it?

Comment: @drissLikeThis I think you'd be better off putting all that into a new question now that you already have answers on this one from the previous wording. We'll need to see your actual code including that part.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the result of that call into a variable, process it then return it

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
  if 'credentials' not in flask.session:
    return flask.redirect('authorize')

  credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
    **flask.session['credentials'])

  client = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)

  # Here is your variable
  channels = channels_list_by_username(client,
    part='snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
    forUsername='username')

  # Process it
  print(channels)
  # Add other processing stuff here

  # Return it
  return channels
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're asking after looking at the source code for youtube API.

`channels_list_by_username()` `print`s some info to stdout. You don't want to print it, you want the actual data, in order to process it, right? Quick glance at that API, I'd guess you could try something like this:

```
...
client = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
      API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)

results = client.channels().list(
    part='snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
    forUsername='username'
  ).execute()

... process data here ...
return results
```

Looks like your code comes from the youtube API example, which is only meant to show how to implement the API. Check the actual docs to see how to get the raw data.

Comment: yes! exactly! and yes, the code in my thread is the API example, I couldn't find the official docs to see how I could alter it to my needs, got lost in hundreds of their links